# How can I list all possibilities of a 3x3 board with 3 different states?

Tags: python

I'm trying to list every possibility of a 3x3 grid, with 3 states: 0, 1, and 2. The board is in the format of a list, so we're listing

```
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], 
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], 
[2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], 
[0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

etc.

I have attempted to do this by counting like this: http://hastebin.com/ozapigageb.py, but it results in a counting that for some reason generates only 1s. I'd either like to know a more efficient way to do that, or what I'm doing wrong. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Do the results need to be in that order?

Comment: No, they don't. Forgot to add that.

Comment: It sounds like you're talking about `3**81`, or `443426488243037769948249630619149892803` different boards.  How long do you have to list them?

Comment: @tom10: I think OP means 3x3, not 9x9

Comment: @Blender: interesting.  OK, do you believe this enough to edit the question.  Anyway, 20000 boards is still a lot to list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `itertools.product`:

```
for board in itertools.product([0, 1, 2], repeat=9):
    ...
```

In your code, you were more or less implementing addition with carrying in base 3. You could represent every single board as an integer between 0 and `3^9 - 1 = 19,682` and reduce your problem to just converting base 10 to base 3:

```
def base_convert(n, base):
    if n == 0:
        return [0]

    digits = []

    while n:
        digits.append(n % base)
        n /= base

    return digits[::-1]

for n in range(3**9):
    digits = base_convert(n, 3)
    board = ([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] + digits)[-9:]  # pad with 0s to 9 digits

    ...
```

Comment: What is "board" in this? Is it a list like [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]?

Comment: @MiseroMCS: It's a tuple, but you can convert it into a list with `list(board)`.

Comment: Okay, I'll look at that.
EDIT: So apparently looking up all this stuff has entered me into google's job interview challenge page. No joke. http://fortune.com/2015/08/27/google-has-a-very-clever-recruiting-trick/

Answer (score 1):

Blender's answer is best, it's good to use Python built-ins when you can. But here's one that's more "down and dirty", and you might find enjoyable if you like math.

Simply count up in base 3, this will enumerate all your (3x3) possibilities. Zero fill so that each number is 9 digits, then extract the digits into their "bins".

```
def base10_to_base3(num):
    result = 0
    factor = 1
    while (num > 0):
        result += num % 3 * factor
        num /= 3
        factor *= 10
    return result

for number in xrange(3**9):
    base3 = base10_to_base3(number)
    result_string = str(base3).zfill(9)
    print [int(digit) for digit in result_string]
```

Comment: I suggest using `xrange` so you don't spend time loading the array

Comment: Good idea! Edited to use xrange.